# How to fix 'Undefined function 'xxx' in expression' (Excel Function in SQL Query)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to call an Excel function to a SQL query, but I keep getting the same error : "Undefined function xxx in expression".

I'm working with Excel only due to customer choices.

I've checked if references were missing,
My function is in a valid Module wiht Option Explicit, and it is declared as Public.
And i made sure I had a return value.

Thank you for your time

There is my function

```vb
Public Function CalculRamasseCarriste(ByVal lng_QTE As Integer, ByVal str_CodeArticle As String, ByVal lng_QTEmax As Integer) As Boolean

    Static lng_cumulQTE         As Integer
    Static str_Text             As String
    Static bln_Prendre          As Boolean


    If str_Text = "" Then
        str_Text = str_CodeArticle
    ElseIf str_Text <> "" Then
         If str_Text <> str_CodeArticle Then
            str_Text = str_CodeArticle
            lng_cumulQTE = 0
         End If
    End If

    lng_cumulQTE = lng_cumulQTE + lng_QTE


    If lng_cumulQTE < lng_QTEmax Then
        CalculRamasseCarriste = True
        bln_Prendre = True
    ElseIf lng_cumulQTE >= lng_QTEmax And bln_Prendre = True Then
        CalculRamasseCarriste = True
        bln_Prendre = False
    Else
        CalculRamasseCarriste = False
    End If

End Function
```

And there is my query :

```vb
    Return_Qry_Ramasse = "SELECT T1.[Adresse], T1.[N° Support], T1.[Code_Article], T1.[Libellé_article] " & _
                         " FROM [V_Stock$] as T1 " & _
                         " LEFT JOIN [Cmd$] as T2 on T1.[Code_Article] = T2.[Code_Article] " & _
                         " WHERE CalculRamasseCarriste(T1.[Nb Box-Colis / Pal], T1.[Code_Article], T2.[UVC_cmd])= True " & _
                         " ORDER BY [Code_Article], [Adresse], [N° Support]"
```

Comment: The issue is the sql engine you're sending the query too doesn't recognize it has a function. So, either make the function in what I assume is sql server, or figure out how to work around this.

Comment: It isn't sql server, i'm working on excel only, my database is on another workbook.

Comment: So youre saying the data source is another excel file? You either need to have that file reference the excel book with the funciton or move the function to that workbook as well. Functions dont magically travel from book to book/ accdb to accdb - they need to be assoicated somehow before their "ubiquitous." Luckily, it sounds like your issue is easily resolved by adding the appropriate workbook as a reference. IMO if you really only using excel everywhere, you should consider an external book to be used as a master function/class repository.

Comment: I wish i was able to use Access but our Customer doesn't want to !
I've tried to paste the module into my database excel file, but it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: When you say you've tried to copy your module to database file, can you explain what you did? If you **database** workbook is an xlsx file, it should have thrown a message to say if you want to save it as a macro file

Comment: I changed the file extension from xlsx to xlsm, then I made a copy of my module with my function in the new workbook. Then I changed in my parameters the name of my file.
Was it stupid ? :D

Comment: Conection is still made, and the error occurs when I try to open my recordset.